# Extra Copy of New Rsync Files

Tags: bash, shell, rsync

I am attempting to mirror a directory on a remote server using rsync.  However, I would like a copy of all newly created files to be stored in a separate directory on the local machine.

For example, if a new file is added on the remote server, I would like it to mirror regularly (for example, to ~/mirror), but save an additional copy of only the new file in another folder, (for example, ~/staging).  To be clear, only the *new* files should appear in staging.

My first approach was to allow rsync to update the timestamps, and then use that to make a copy.  However, I would now like to preserve timestamps.

Can anyone provide ideas on a simple approach?  I am open to use of additional utilities other than rsync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider making hardlinks in the extra directory.

```
ln --force --target-directory=~/staging ~/mirror/*
```

**Edit:**

If this is a Linux system, [`incron`](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) will trigger on `inotify` events and would allow you to make copies of files as they are added to a directory you specify.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am specifically looking for only the new files to be copied to the ~/staging directory.  Hard-linking everything would cause all files to appear in the staging directory.

I have updated my description to make this more clear.